# Resolvent set of perturbed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Let $A_0:\mathcal{H} \supset \mathcal{D}(A_0) \to \mathcal{H}$ be a densely defined (by $\mathcal{D}(A_0)$ I denote a domain of an operator $A_0$), closed and self-adjoint operator acting on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let $z \in \rho(A_0)$, so there exist $(A_0 - zI)^{-1}$ and it is bounded. Let $V: \mathcal{H} \supset \mathcal{D}(V) \to \mathcal{H}$ be a densely defined symmetric operator and $\mathcal{D}(A_0)\subset \mathcal{D}(V)$. My question is, if it is true that $z \in \rho(A_0+V)$?

Comment: Take $A_0 = \Bbb 1$, $V=-\Bbb 1$. Then $0\in \rho(A_0)$ but...